# Why do Chinese novelists sometimes have the same name as their characters?

Tags: name-significance, chinese-language

I've encountered this twice now:

1. *这世界，缺你不可* by 吴大伟 ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=AgpOEAAAQBAJ)) has a character named 大伟 (pinyin: Dà​wěi).
2. *谢谢你曾来过我的世界* by 仲尼 ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books?id=1jD1vQEACAAJ)) has a character named 仲尼 (pinyin: Zhòng​ní).

I'm puzzled as to what's happening here.  I've never seen this in English novels.  It's possible the authors are using a pen name, but I'm not sure.

**Question**: Why do Chinese novelists sometimes have the same name as their characters?

Comment: It [does happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Darren_Shan) in English too.

Comment: I haven't read the novels. Given both names are English transliterations, and from the titles and the first page preview, they seem pretty preoccopied with identity. ("David and I were the same age and spoke the same words ...") ... so I would guess the pseudonym is a way to extend that ambiguity slightly beyond the pages of the novel.

Comment: Other English examples: *Money* has a (minor) character called "Martin Amis", and *The Word is Murder* and its sequels are narrated by a character called "Anthony Horowitz".

Comment: And yet [another English example](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/m/pat-murphy/adventures-in-time-and-space-with-max-merriwell.htm): in *Adventures in Time and Space with Max Merriwell*, the narrator's best friend is named Pat Murphy. And I know I've seen other examples of this.